# syntax error on else, delete this token error

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

My if, else statement is giving me an error that is telling me to delete the word else. What should I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double GradeAverage;
        {
            System.out.print("Welcome! Please enter in your mid-year grade average.");
        }
        Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);

        {
            GradeAverage = kbdln.nextDouble();
            {
                if (GradeAverage > 60 && GradeAverage <= 100);
                {
                    System.out.print("You're passing your class!");
                }
                else if (GradeAverage > 0 && GradeAverage <= 60)
          {System.out.print("Hook up with a smart classmate and STUDY!");}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lose that semicolon after your `if` condition; it's acting as the body of your `if` statement.

Comment: What does `;` do? What happens if you put it after an `if` statement?

Comment: It would just end the `if` condition.

Comment: It may be a good idea to enable [auto formatting if you are using eclipse](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/12/13/automatically-format-and-cleanup-code-every-time-you-save/).

Answer (score 4):

There should be no semi-colon after the if statements.

The if statement should be as follows:

```
if(GradeAverage > 60 && GradeAverage <= 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get rid of all those `{ }` you are using. It is way too much. Although it is correct to use them to declare a *local namespace* and absolutely necessary to use them with your `if-else` statements. But it is better not to use *local namespaces* if you are not absolutely sure what you are doing.

The second thing is you have a `;` after your if statement. Which will be interpreted as an `; = empty statement`. So your follow up `else` is completely alone – and that's why your IDE tells you to remove the `else`.

Here is a version of your code *a little cleaned up* :)

```
public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double GradeAverage;
        System.out.print("Welcome! Please enter in your mid-year grade average.");
        Scanner kbdln = new Scanner(System.in);

        GradeAverage = kbdln.nextDouble();
        if (GradeAverage > 60 && GradeAverage <= 100) {
            System.out.print("You're passing your class!");
        } else if (GradeAverage > 0 && GradeAverage <= 60) {
            System.out.print("Hook up with a smart classmate and STUDY!");
        }
    }
}
```